# How to send Playback Analytic Events

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

Trying to create a new (my First) Bixby app, starting to get the hang of it. One question, we have a requirement to send playback analytics when certain sponsorship elements play.

How do we track these events off the Audio Player? Is there any sort of event system that we can tap into?

(we technically also need to make these tracks unskippable which doesn't seem possible)

Bixby Studio with audioPlayer (0.3.13)

Comment: Please provide code examples of what you have tried; https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

1. analytics is possible using API calls, but developer must track it in their own JS code.
2. there is no system event handle. That is, if you want to find out how many user decided to skip a track, that is not supported at the moment.
3. for mobile device, skip track is always supported (if there are multiple tracks) , so is the pause/resume command. It is handle as a part of Bixby meta-command, not individual capsule.